# Simple way of moving root web application to child application of another site?

Tags: iis-7, migration

We have an IIS 7 site that is really very complicated, and also undocumented (lots of virtual directories, child applications etc).

We want to move it from its current position (www.xyz.com) to be a child folder of another site (www.abc.com), effectively making something like www.abc.com/xyz/<*site files*>

Obviously you cant  drag and drop it to another site so i was wondering if there was an 'easier' way to copy this web application to another folder, rather than going through each folder/iis 7 setting.

Answer (score 0):

Since all IIS7 settings are stored in the web.config files in each subfolder, it should be pretty simple. Try to just create a new application under /xyz and point it to the same folder that www.xyz.com points to.

The only problem is the web.config in the root of www.abc.com, which might conflict with the web.config in www.abc.com/xyz. Then you have to override in www.abc.com/xyz

I have never done this for a complex web app, but I hope it works ;)